# Killing "session" with SignalR, OWIN, and Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr, owin

It has been a long road but I have SignalR working with my Web API which uses OWIN for token authentication.

I have a mechanism where if a user authenticates on terminal #1 and then later authenticates on terminal #2, I can send them a Javascript alert saying "Hey, only one session at a time. Which one do you want to log out?"

The question I have is how to kill their "session" on one of the terminals? I say "session", but since this is a REST based API there really is no session. If I could force them to re-authenticate on the terminal they choose to "log out" from that would be sufficient.

I have the SignalR `connectionId` of each client. Is there a way I can expire their authentication token and force a logout?

**Note** - The client is separate from the Web API in that they are hosted on two different servers. The client is just HTML/Javascript making calls to the Web API.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a bearer token approach, and you are not storing tokens (or token hashes) into some kind of persistent storage (e.g. a DB), then you have no way to *invalidate* a token.

Since [OAuth is not an Authentication protocol](http://oauth.net/articles/authentication/), it do not have any kind of *log out* concept in it. Your only option is to remove the token from the client storage (I can imagine it is stored inside the localStorage or in a cookie).

Of course this does not really invalidate anything, and if the token is not deleted for some reason, it can still be used for authorization purposes.

Your only option, if you really need a single access token valid at a single time, is to store some information about it in a database, and check that storage every time you validate the token. You could, for instance, store the hash of the token (never store the real token for [this reason](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86913/should-password-reset-tokens-be-hashed-when-stored-in-a-database), they have the same value of passwords once stored) with the username, but please note that this approach makes your authorization protocol *a little less stateless* than before.

Comment: Since the token is being passed in the header for each request to the API would there be a way to delete it from the header?

Comment: What do you mean when you say *from the header*? From the client requests log?

Comment: When I use Postman to test the API I first authenticate with the API and I receive a token that is passed along in the header. If this token is deleted or changed then the web client would need to authenticate again to get a valid token. So when I say header I mean the HTTP Header that is passed along when calling an API method.

Comment: Since you will remove token using SignalR, no, there is no way to delete the token from clients not under your control. This brings again the DB/persistent storage option as your only valid alternative.

Comment: I know they connectionId of the client that needs to be "logged off". So I can invoke javascript code on the client. In looking at Postman the access token is passed in the `Authorization` header. If I could just alter that token that should prevent the client from accessing further API methods shouldn't it?

Comment: In your client (a SPA i suppose?), of course you can. Just remove the token from wherever you have stored it before (localStorage, sessionStorage, or a simple javascript variable, maybe?), so that any further API calls would fail because no token is found.

Comment: That would be exactly what I am looking for. I just need to figure out how to alter/remove the Authorization header using Javascript! Thanks for your help! and yes it is a SPA :)

Comment: what about Logout action method in Account controller??